# once-beautiful meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I am wondering to know the **once-beautiful** meaning where I could not find its meaning in the dictionary or internet!

> The once-beautiful building was now dirty, decrepit, and roofless.

Comment: Have you checked the word "once" in a dictionary, especially the adverb once!

Comment: It may be helpful to know that this is in fact two words, being joined for no apparent reason by a hyphen.  Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341670/now-forgotten-vs-now-forgotten-once-powerful-vs-once-powerful/341673

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It simply means the building used to be beautiful previously.

"once" means:

> at some time in the past; formerly.
>
> <sup>*(from Google)*</sup>

So, "once-beautiful" means the building was beautiful previously and stands in contrast to its current state - "dirty, decrepit, and roofless".

You can add "once" to almost any adjective, such as "once-important".